# How to use clang::TreeTransform?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, transformation, abstract-syntax-tree

i'm trying to figure out the integration point for the clang::TreeTransform.

The goal is to transform the AST before the Code Generation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @Nawaz which docuentation? - I didn't find any pages about TreeTransform

Comment: The doxygen doc for LLVM, such as [this](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TreeTransform.html#details) ... and yes, you have to work a little bit to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Nawaz thanks for the link, that's where i learned about TreeTransform in the first place. However it does not mention where to inject or run a TreeTransformer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [ASTFrontEndAction](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html), then redefine the method  CreateASTConsumer in order to create a SemaConsumer (instead of an ASTConsumer).

Then in handleTopLevelDecl method create a RecursiveASTVisitor by handing it the Sema, which will be necessary for TreeTransform.

Then the Visit method of the RecursiveASTVisitor can create an instance of your TreeTransform, and then call the appropriate transforming method.

PS: Sometimes when tranforming compund statements, function scope might by empty. You can do

```
SemaRef.PushFunctionScope();
SemaRef.PushCompoundScope();
```

before you call your tranforming function.

Comment: Note: I've found TreeTransform is part of the private interface an that it does not support adding new nodes very well. http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Tree-transformation-in-clang-td3547216.html